# Dynamically add a div INSIDE an input field while typing

Tags: jquery, input, zendesk

I am trying to simulate what Zendesk does in their signup form for the subdomain.  As the user starts to type a subdomain, it automagically adds ".zendesk.com" in a different color to what the user is typing.

It appears that it's another div that is positioned, but I have no idea how they are positioning it perfectly after the typed input AS the user types.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Without seeing their page or code, is it possible they have a replica input aligned in the same position as the one you type in? It also mirrors the input and just appends the ".zendesk.com" at the end of the string after each keystroke? That seems like a relatively simple way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way of doing it would be to have an input at the same position mirror the actual input the user is typing in and just add the string to the end of the value on change.

So you have

```
<input class="mirrorInput" disabled="disabled"></input>
<input class="realInput"></input>​
```

with

```
.realInput{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: none;
}

.mirrorInput{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: green;
    background: white;
}
```

and the JS is simply

```
$(".realInput").on("keyup", function(event){
    $(".mirrorInput").val($(".realInput").val() + ".zendesk.com");
})
```

[Here's a fiddle showing how it could work.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/x83vD/)

Comment: Dude, tha is a great and simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: Question though, how exactly is the mirror input visible from behind the typed input?  Is an input field transparent?

Comment: @JoshL the realInput has a background property of "none" which makes it transparent.

Comment: nice.  didnt see that.  love css3

Comment: actually I found an issue with your solution but also a solution to that issue :)  If you tab from other fields you end up selecting the mirrorInput, which lets you delete the zendesk part.  Not good  To fix, just add a $(".mirrorInput").focus(function() { $(".realInput").focus() }); and all is well!

Comment: Actually found a better way as my solution didnt allow for reverse tabbing - simply add disabled="disabled" to the mirrorInput and change the background color to white.

Comment: Good call adding disabled to it so you can't tab to it or interact with it. Added that to the answer for posterity.